# Referencing a Launch image

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to include a launch image referenced in the `Info.plist` under `UILaunchImages` with a `UILaunchImageSize` value set to `{320, 568}`. Is this the correct way of doing it?

The message I got after submitting my app "must include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to {320, 568}".

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>Launch image </key>
<string>Default@2x-iphone.png</string>
<key>UILaunchImageName</key>
<string>Default</string>
<key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
<string>{320,568}</string>
<key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>7.0</string>
</dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your info.plist file add a new entry (line) and make it of type array and name it UILaunchImages.

Under it add another item of type dictionary. this dictionary will be the image reference you are looking for.

To This dictionary add the following keys and values:

- UILaunchImageSize: {320, 568}
- UILaunchImageName: Default-568h@2x (<-this is your image file's name)
- UILaunchImageNameMinimumOSVersion: 7.0 (or what ever is applicable for your project)
- UILaunchImageOrientation: portrait

make sure all launch images you need are referenced this way in your info.plist file.

check out [Charlies great answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182966/your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-after-i-upload-an-app-with-xcode-6-0)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how to name the image, it's usually Default-568h@2x.png (for 4-inch).

It's easier if you don't edit the Info.plist file directly and just set your default images in the General tab of the XCode project settings.

Comment: its cause I submitted my app and it said I needed to do that in order for it to be accepted

Answer (score 0):

In the Project Navigator of Xcode, click on the project, go to the General tab and scroll down to where you see a section labeled Launch Images. It'll have all the necessary resolutions and you can just click on the arrows and add images.

Comment: yeah Ive already added the images in the asset catalog and made sure I've selected them under the general tab but if thats all I can do regarding launch images then the launch images are not my problem rather its about supporting the 4-inch display on iPhone 5