# "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5" after I upload an app with xcode 6.0.1

Tags: xcode, localization, app-store-connect

I am getting this email after upload my binary with Xcode Version 6.0.1 (6A317)

> Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - - New iPhone apps and app
>   updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must
>   include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under
>   UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to {320, 568}.
>   Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your
>   bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your
>   launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images
>   by reviewing the 'iOS Human Interface Guidelines' at
>   'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5'
>   and the 'iOS App Programming Guide' at
>   'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12'.

Here is my plist file:

[image]

Here is my Xcode tree:

[image]

Here is my bundle root tree:

[image]

Here is the only resource I could find on this issue but it remains unanswered (3 days old)... https://devforums.apple.com/message/1051948#1051948

Comment: could you select an answer for this?  @Charlie Hung's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We faced the same issue and couldn't solve it after trying many solutions, we believe it's a kind of bug in App submission.
But we found a workaround which can keep launch images localized and pass the submission verification.

**Environment:**

Xcode 6.1 (6A1052c) with iOS 8.1 SDK

**Precondition:**

Have following properties in your "*-info.plist" file.

[image]

**Steps:**

1. Go to your target's settings and in our standard scenario (localize
   launch images, which uses "UILaunchImages" in "*-info.plist" but not
   image assets), it should look like the image
   [image]
2. Change the setting to use image assets (Note: after this step, Xcode will automatically REMOVE the "UILaunchImages" properties in your *-info.plist file. So please BACKUP the properties first.)
3. Go to the "LaunchImage" assets (can click the arrow button on the right) and fill with images from one of your *.lproj folder.
   [image]
4. Now, go to the "LaunchImage" folder which contains images and "Contents.json" file.
   [image]
5. Remove ALL the launch **IMAGES** just added, but keep the "Contents.json" (and it's content) file.
6. Check the "Contents.json", it should contains properties like image below
   [image]

**Double check following items:**

- Localized launch images in resource folders (en.lproj, ja.lproj, etc.)
- *-info.plist contains "UILaunchImages" properties
- Project setting uses image asset for launch images
- "Contents.json" in "LaunchImage" asset folder, and the folder **DOES NOT** really have launch images

Now you can have a try for localized launch images and submit the binary to iTunes Connect. In our App, the workaround did work for "**localized launch images**" and "**submission successful**".

It should be a trick for avoiding the bug in submission checking.

Since the workaround above doesn't change any resource, except making the checking thinks we use image assets, we are more convinced that there are some bugs in Apple's checking.

Cheers!

Comment: actually, i just tried ur solution, it s defenitely works. but , no need to be so complicate,  just 2 points need to check in order to make submission successful:  1.  Project setting uses image asset for launch images,   2. "Contents.json" in "LaunchImage" asset folder and the folder DOES NOT really have launch images
  as for info.plist, u dont really need to check anything on there, as xcode will compile everything correctly if you done those above two steps

Comment: This makes my blood boil.

Comment: So you say to remove the launch images from the contents.json file you took a screenshot of?

Comment: This is confusing. Should I remove the images from the folder? But they still need to exist, right? Where do you place them? Randomly? So info.plist contains UILaunchImages properties, then I set the project to use image assets for launch images. And then what I said above? It gets me really mad because I don't think it should be this weirdly fixed.

Comment: @CarmenA The localized launch images should be put in the localization resource files like en.lproj, jp.lproj, etc. 
I don't think this is a solution, either. But to meet our goal, "successful submission", "localized launch images" and using image asset for other images, it's the workaround for us.

Comment: @Morkrom Remove "IMAGES" beside contents.json but keeps contents.json and it's content.

Comment: This looks like a terribly hacky solution.   It should be Simple.

Comment: It worked! Though our project didn't have any localized assets - it worked without that part. The files however needed to be in the bundle root. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me too. Since iOS6 (I think) if you localize your app you must be consistent all the way. You have English, Dutch, and French as languages as I see in the screen shot. You must have these languages EVERYWHERE you do localization. Your string localization files must have all these languages but not more languages.
I got the same reply when I used AppiRater library for an app. AppiRater has messages in many languages and my app is localized only for 2 languages. So I had to delete all the other string files from AppiRater except the 2 that I needed.
Once I did that everything went well.

So the short answer is: delete any extra localization files that you don't need to support and add localization files that are missing from your app.

Cheers!

**Edit by danielgindi**

This actually works, despite some claims that this answer is irrelevant.
It happened to me when I started using Base localization in an app, and it still had some resources localized in `en.lproj` folder, including the `Default.png`s.

So you can either make sure that you have the `Default-568h@2x.png` file in *all* of the localization folders that you are using - or delete localizations that you are not using. 
I have just moved everything to be in `Base.lproj`, so this way it's clear what png it is taking, and there's no duplicate.

Comment: Your answer seems irrelevant. Why would it be related? And if so, how can I managed to ensure I am consistent in my localizations if I use Cocoa Pods?

Comment: It is not unrelated. I encountered the same problem telling me about the png incompatibility even though it had nothing to do with it. And I fixedit like I state in my answer. Regarding the Cocoa Pods thing I'm not sure what to tell you, but there are chances that your problem has to do with the localisations like I've said.

Comment: Actually I can confirm that it IS related. I'm going to edit the answer to make a little clearer.

Answer (score 3):

### To Be more Clear:

1. Change your launch image source to "Launch Image" (follow steps 1-3 in @Charlie Hung's answer).

[image]

2. Right click on your project and select 'Show in Finder'
3. Find folder **Assets.xcassets** and open it
4. Open the **LaunchImage.launchimage** folder and move your two images to your .Iproj folder which you'll find in your project. (Mine was called Base.Iproj).

Finally, add this to your info.plist (open in text editor):

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
      <string>7.0</string>
      <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
      <string>iOS7-Default </string>
      <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
      <string>Portrait</string>
      <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
      <string>{320, 480}</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

This is all I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was updating an older app. It turned out I was missing an icon file named: launchiPhone5-568h@2x.png with dimensions 320x568.  I found this by looking through the warnings.  I created the file, added it to my project with the other icon files and it worked fine.

Hope that helps someone :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do what Charlie and Dan recommend AND make sure that your image file names don't have any dashes in it.  Mine didn't work until I renamed the files as only alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but in my case I didn't had the storyboard (xib) file for the launch image, which is needed:

"You use a launch XIB or storyboard file **to indicate** that your app runs on iPhone 6 Plus or iPhone 6." ([see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html))

I followed this tutorial to create it:
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/templates/launchscreen-xib/

For step 9 of the turorial, in the Info.plist, I set:

```
<key>UILaunchImageFile~iphone</key>
<string>Launch Screen.storyboard</string>
```

[image: info.plist adding key launch image and string storyboard file]

Just to verify, when you run your app, you should see your launch screen image before it loads.  After I did this, I was able to upload the app to the app store.

Steps showed above in other answers are also important: "If you also need to support earlier versions of iOS, you can continue to supply static launch images in addition to a launch file." ([see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html))

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in deployment environment 9.3 and swift 2.3 and in my case I didn't had the storyboard (xib) file for the launch image, which is needed and my configuration was wrong in projects target settings, see the image link below:

[Picture of Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O95qC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is useful for some guys: just change the `iOS Deployment Target` from 7.0 to 8.1 or higher.

[image]

I met this problem when I want to upload an app to app store built by react-native 0.37, and its default `iOS Deployment Target` is 7.0.