# Definitive and actualized answer on Localization of LaunchImages

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, app-store-connect

This [IOS: launch image multiple language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411308/ios-launch-image-multiple-language/9411515#comment41113716_9411515) dates back to 2012.

It is a procedure that works well when running the app both on simulator and devices.

However, it fails `itunesconnect` validation after submit (**invalid binary**).

> Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - - New iPhone apps and app
>   updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must
>   include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under
>   UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to {320, 568}.
>   Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your
>   bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your
>   launch images.

Also see ["Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5" after I upload an app with xcode 6.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182966/your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-after-i-upload-an-app-with-xcode-6-0)

So despite it's possible to localize spalshscreen on development, is it possible to do it for real?

Comment: This other answer may help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191641/my-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-while-having-localized-splash-screens