# Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 xcassets

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, launchimage

First thing: i read the other answers to this common problem but they didn't solve my issue, so i'm asking here cause i can't understand why it doesn't work.

As you can imagine, my problem is:

[image: error displayed]

I'm using `xcode 6` and `Swift` as language. I use `Images.xcassets` as default for launch images located under `Supporting Files`.

[image: Here are the images]

Here is my `Images.xcassets` screenshot:

[image: images.xcassets]

The images are simply blank .png images with right resolution.
As you can see in the last row, there is also the `LaunchImage` for iPhone 5.
In my project general settings, `Images.xcassets` is set as `Launch Images Source`.

P.s. i know that this question was asked a lot of times, but also if i read the previous answers i couldn't find a solution.

Comment: It's probably not connected in the project settings.

Comment: You should not have both a the launch images in the assets catalog and the support files directory. Check you project settings for you target and set it up to use the assets catalog launch images.

Comment: As I said, it's connected to launch images source..

Comment: it looks your Images.xcassets folder is empty

Comment: This is because my images are all blank images!

Comment: Have you tried just using a LaunchImage.xib? If you're only going to use a blank image (even, if you aren't), it's a good solution. Just remember to link the xib in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update March 2, 2015

If you don't want to use a storyboard file, but want to just make your current assets work, it sounds like you're missing the reference in Info.plist. The issue is described here (with solution): ["Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5" after I upload an app with xcode 6.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182966/your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-after-i-upload-an-app-with-xcode-6-0). You can also view the Info.plist key list here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW24

---

Using a LaunchScreen Storyboard file will eliminate this problem. There's a good tutorial here: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/.

Basically, you have to create a blank storyboard file called `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. Then, in your target settings (the general tab), set your launch screen file.

[image]

Add a view controller to the scene and position subviews in it to match your interface. Or, you can add the view controller and just leave it blank if you want.

Xcode will prioritize your LaunchScreen file over any assets, so you don't have to delete them immediately if you don't want to.

Next, build the project to test it. Archive. And try to submit again.

Comment: Sorry for this late answer but using the LaunchScreen the error remains. I created a launch screen and set it as default, infact when i open my app, it works, but the error i described above remained..

Comment: Is the key in info.plist?

Comment: Finally i was able to submit the app! I'll accept your answer cause it gives me the idea!