# ERROR ITMS-90096: Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am using LaunchScreen.storyboard file to load Splash screen images. Not creating manually images to drag and drop to image asset folder. I dig so many posts to apply on same issue but none of them worked well for me. Every time getting the same error.

Also I am attaching the error screen shots for getting more help.[image]

I had refered the below links but its not working for me

["Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5" after I upload an app with xcode 6.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182966/your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-after-i-upload-an-app-with-xcode-6-0)
https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/2fqjwt/your_binary_is_not_optimized_for_iphone_issue/
["Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5" (ITMS-90096) when submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830013/your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-itms-90096-when-submitting)
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21969

Comment: because you missing image in launch screen add 320*568 size image

Comment: @Jigar I am not using any manual Splash images.

Comment: @Eric Aya, I have found so many posts regarding this Error message but all of them are guiding me to add All Splash size screens except LaunchScreen Storyboard. If you have any answer or post regarding to my question you can share it with me. It will be appreciate for me.

Comment: I've reopened your question, but *please* [edit] it and explain how this duplicate link didn't work for you. Otherwise your question will certainly be closed as duplicate again to the same link by other users.

Comment: @GautamSareriya - This is very common error for projects only using launch screen.storyboard. You still need to add 1 image to support iPhone5 , way to fix is adding launch image in assets.