# NativeScript iOS publish: Error ITMS-90096 "not optimized for iPhone 5

Tags: ios, xcode, typescript, nativescript

First of: I am running on Xcode 7. I also tried with Xcode 8.
I want to publish my iOS Application and tried to run

```
tns publish iOS
```

Sadly I get the following output:

```
Package Summary:

1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
    /var/folders/nl/z3cdbrb17776dtxlltdqvc4h0000gn/T/itms-117820-1943-lu4nqt.pqlz93sor/mybundle.itmsp - Error Messages:
        ERROR ITMS-90096: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to {320, 568}. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images by reviewing the 'iOS Human Interface Guidelines' at https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen."
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon29x29'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon40x40'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon57x57'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon60x60'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon50x50'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon72x72'"
        ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon76x76'"
        ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
        ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
        ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter failed with exit code 1
```

After researching a while I found the following post:

[ERROR ITMS-90096: Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 Xcode 8.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42716013/error-itms-90096-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-xcode-8-2-1)

which says, that I need to run this command under iOS version 8.0 or higher. So I tried to execute

```
tns publish ios --sdk 8.0
```

which did produce the same outcome.

My info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>$my_app</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>2.0.7</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>2.0.7</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        $some_stuff
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My Content.json for my images:

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-29.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-29@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-29@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-40@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-40@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "57x57",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-57.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "57x57",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-57@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "60x60",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-60@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "60x60",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "icon-60@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-29.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-29@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-40.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-40@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "50x50",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-50.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "50x50",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-50@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "72x72",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-72.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "72x72",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-72@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "76x76",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-76.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "76x76",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-76@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "83.5x83.5",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-83.5@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

So everything should be provided and I do not know what else to do. I can run this application without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this for days, and mine turned out to be a combo of issues.

if you have xcode I recommend you use that to build your archive it will show you warnings that are very helpful.

You can see that some of the images required are missing from your contents.json file. I used this site to build my app icons http://nsimage.brosteins.com/ which should take care of all the size errors it complains about (120x120, etc.)

It won't resolve the optimized for iphone 5 however.

the image tool does a great job, but some of the images were the wrong size for the launch screen image.

I don't have the exact sizes right now, but you'll see in the xcode warnings something like 'Default-568.png has a size of 320x568 but should be 320x480.' create those images with the dimensions its expecting.

lastly, put these images Default-568.png Default-568h@2x.png in the root, and for a nativescript app, by root i mean platforms>ios

then add this to your info.plist

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>7.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-568h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 568}</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```